# Can't execute javascript into webview

Tags: java, android, android-studio, webview

Whenever I am trying to execute javascript using loadUrl, it either navigates to a blank page with my javascript value or completely blank page.

I have tried almost every solution that I could find on the internet. Whatever I have tried ends up as blank page or blank page with my value as a textView(label) with no css.

```java
         final WebView webView;
        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webView.loadUrl("https://www.google.com/");

    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

         public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

             webView.loadUrl("alert('sound')");
             //webView.loadUrl("javascript:alert('ssss')");
//webView.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementsByName('txtUserName').value = 'kekk'");




         }
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

From KitKat onwards, you should use `evaluateJavascript`, check it out in the docs [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView#evaluateJavascript(java.lang.String,%2520android.webkit.ValueCallback%3Cjava.lang.String%3E)).

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I was using _loadurl_ probably because all the examples are from 2016 or before that, although _evaluateJavascript_ didn't work(nothing pops up) probably its my code I'll have to create a new project probably by the way I have found this [link](https://github.com/googlearchive/chromium-webview-samples) I'll look into it. :)

Comment: It all depends on what Android version you are running your code on. Pre-KitKat you should use loadUrl indeed.